# In my Expo React-Native app, how do I prevent the 'Unable to add output to camera session' message from appearing?

Tags: react-native, camera, expo

Recently I'm getting the message 'Unable to add output to camera session! Face detection aborted!' whenever recordAsync finishes recording. I need to use both the face detector and the recording feature--not necessarily at the same.

I upgraded my expo SDK version from 33.0.0 to 34.0.0 to see if that would make any difference.

My logic is similar to this:

```js
import React from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Dimensions,
  AsyncStorage,
  Button,
  Image
} from 'react-native';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';
import * as FaceDetector from 'expo-face-detector';
import * as Location from 'expo-location';
import { ScreenOrientation } from 'expo';
import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions';
import * as Progress from 'react-native-progress';
import { Camera } from 'expo-camera';

...

<Camera
          ref={ref => { this.camera = ref; }}
          style={{ flex: 1 }}
          zoom={this.state.zoom}
          onMountError={this.handleMountError}
          onFacesDetected={this.state.shouldDetectFaces ? this.handleFacesDetected : null}
          faceDetectorSettings={{
            mode: FaceDetector.Constants.Mode.fast,
            detectLandmarks: FaceDetector.Constants.Landmarks.none,
            runClassifications: FaceDetector.Constants.Classifications.none,
          }}
          onFaceDetectionError={this.onFaceDetectionError}
        ...
      />
```

I receive this abort error message when recording is completed, even though I set `shouldDetectFaces` to false.

[image: https://i.postimg.cc/PfQdFQmq/67527765-490709274835678-5752542955604803584-n.png]

Any ideas on how to prevent the abort error message?

Comment: Have you imported the FaceDetector module?

Comment: Thanks for the response! I have installed FaceDetector by running ```expo install expo-face-detector```. is that what you mean? I have also added more details to my current implementation.

Comment: You can try set minDetectionInterval value and tracking value.

Comment: Thanks, just tried that. The error still appears, but at least it's suppressed in production mode, so I guess I'll just ignore it.